# C# I can not print label in Zebra

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

There is a text file that I send to the Zebra printer Zt410,

There is only one button and when I press this button,
 I want to send it to the printer with the following code,

although the code works successfully, nothing comes out of the printer.

```
namespace DenemeLabel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string ipAddress = "..";
                int port = 6101;

                System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
                client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("deneme.txt");
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                string testFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                writer.Write(testFile);
                writer.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
                client.Close();


                MessageBox.Show("OKEY");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea where is the problem?

Comment: Given that you are writing `"Hello World!"` directly to the printer, I assume the file does not contain ZPL commands either.

Comment: As GSerg points, there is no ZPL commands in your code. Instead of "Hello World!" try something like 
"^XA
^CF0,60
^FO50,50
^FDHello World!^FS
^XZ"

Comment: Find here a document about ZPL language for Zebra Printers.

https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Comment: Instead of creating ZPL commands you can use .NET [`PrintDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument) commands that will work on any printer.